# Is there a gzip library available for Rust?

Tags: zlib, rust, gzip

My searches have found:

The [flate](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.11.0/flate/index.html) library, based on [miniz](https://code.google.com/p/miniz/). Edit: as Mark Adler points out, this is a zlib library, but does not deal with gzip headers.

[Snappy](https://code.google.com/p/snappy/) [bindings](https://github.com/thestinger/rust-snappy), which don't compile on modern Rust.

Comment: [Rust-compress](https://github.com/alexcrichton/rust-compress/tree/master) has a zlib implementation, and [these others](http://www.rust-ci.org/projects/#compression) on Rust CI (Rust's de facto package listing for now) may have something: no idea of quality/if they are bug-free, but fixing such things is a fact of life with Rust at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: there is now [flate2](https://crates.io/crates/flate2), [libflate](https://crates.io/crates/libflate) and [deflate](https://crates.io/crates/deflate).

---

So I combined dbaupp's and Mark Adler's advice, and created a gzip-decompressor: https://github.com/alexcrichton/rust-compress/pull/30

However, it turns out that Mr Crichton already wrote a gzip layer: https://github.com/alexcrichton/flate2-rs

For now, those two options exist; it remains to be seen what ends up as the standard Rust solution.

Answer (score 4):

flate generates and processes both raw and zlib-wrapped deflate streams.  A gzip stream, which is what gunzip, zcat, etc. work on, is a *gzip-wrapped* deflate stream.  If you want to use flate, then you need to first process the gzip header, then use flate to decompress the deflate data, and then process the gzip trailer.  The gzip header and trailer is documented in RFC 1952.